# In Xcode, how can I import or use the normal BSD Unix C Library?

Tags: objective-c

The Stanford iOS dev seminar suggests I uses "the normal BSD Unix C" library for calculating sine and cosine. While I can calculate those values on my own just fine, I'm trying to learn more about implementing external libraries.

Where is this library? Is it included by default?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe they're just talking about the `sin` and `cos` functions included in the standard `math.h` header. You can simply add

```
#import <math.h>
```

to the top of your implementation file, then call `sin` and `cos` (with radian arguments). See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/sin/) for function definitions.

**Edit:** Apparently, the default `Foundation` import includes `math.h`, so the `#import` above isn't necessary. I'm only leaving it here for future reference.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I couldn't tell if these were static functions, or do I need to instantiate a Math class first to use them.

Comment: C doesn't have any objects, so there's no class to instantiate. You can just call the methods.

Answer (score 3):

The functions `sin` and `cosine` functions can be used in files that import `math.h`.

By default, Xcode adds `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to all the header files and `Foundation.h` imports `math.h`. So unless you change that, you already have `math.h` imported and can use its functions like `sin`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is included by default.

The standard C library also includes things like `open` to open files and `printf` for formatted text output. Almost all Objective C programs are linked against the standard C library.